# How to make nav go back to transparent at top

Tags: javascript, html, css

My nav changes from transparent to #eee and gains a box-shadow - '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)' when it passes my header h1 tag. How would I do the inverse of this and make it go back to no box-shadow and no fill?

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#header h1');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $("#nav").css('background-color', '#eee');
    $("#nav").css('-webkit-box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
    $("#nav").css('-moz-box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
    $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
       }
   });
    }
});
```

```css
/* nav css */

#nav {
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:75px;
 background-color:transparent;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:auto;
 z-index: 10000;
 top: 0;
 margin:auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align:center;
 transition: background-color 500ms linear;
 
}
#nav ul li {
 width:150px;
 height:75px;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:15px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 margin-top:15px;
}
#nav ul li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#999;
 display:block;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 color:#bdbdbd;
}

/*header css*/

#header {
 position:absolute;
 height:100vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:rgb(164,164,164);
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 z-index:9998;
 margin-top:0;
 background-image:url(../images/mac-header.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

#header h1 {
 position:relative;
 margin-top:40vh;
 display:block;
 font-size:75px;
 color:#eeeeee;
}

#header h3 {
 color:#cccccc;
}

#header h1 {
 -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox < 16 */
   -ms-animation: fadein 5s; /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
     animation: fadein 5s;
}

#prevent {
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
}

#placeholder {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="nav">
 <ul>
        <li id="logo"><a href="index.html"><b>symmetry creative.</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"><b>about us.</b></a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html"><b>services.</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="pricing.html"><b>pricing.</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html"><b>contact.</b></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="header">
 <h1>symmetry creative.</h1>
</div>

<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

snippet may be broke so I apologise, live code is on http://jackfinn3y.co.uk/RJ-Creative/symmetry/website/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript code as follows. You have to write the `else` condition to achieve this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('#header h1');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length) {
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
                $("#nav").css('background-color', '#eee');
                $("#nav").css('-webkit-box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
                $("#nav").css('-moz-box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
                $("#nav").css('box-shadow', '0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
            }
            else {
                $("#nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("#nav").css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'none');
                $("#nav").css('-moz-box-shadow', 'none');
                $("#nav").css('box-shadow', 'none');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
  $("#nav").css('background-color', '#eee');
  // ...
} else {
  $("#nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```

Example

```js
var startChange = $("#header h1");

var offset = startChange.offset();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollStart = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (scrollStart > offset.top - $("#nav").height()) {
    $("#nav").css({
      'background-color': '#eee'
    });
  } else {
    $("#nav").css({
      'background-color': 'transparent'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

#nav {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

<div id="header">
  <h1>Adipisicing quos vitae itaque provident?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You have JavaScript code that specifically sets the CSS when you scroll below the offset `if(scroll_start > offset.top) { ... }`, but you don't do anything when you scroll back up.

You just need to remove the styles when you're over the offset again:

```
   if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
     // your existing code
   } else {
     // new code to set style when scroll is above offset
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go